# Are there Ubuntu security notices feeds for specific releases

Tags: security, web-feed

The [Ubuntu security notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) web page has an option to show only notices for a single release. Is there a way to **get notices for a single release as a feed**, without setting it up myself? That is, is there an official feed containing all and only Ubuntu 12.04 (for example) security notices?

The end goal is a tool which warns when any of a set of packages (not necessarily the ones installed on a system) for a single Ubuntu release are affected by a security notice.

Comment: Could you explain us more ?

Comment: I tried filtering using Feed Rinse and Yahoo! Pipes but didn't find a satisfactory way to do it. You might consider starting a wishlist item for this on Launchpad. There is [precedent](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/71685).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/1060366) based on @ændrük's comment.

> **Ubuntu Security Notice feeds per release**
>
> Following up on [bug #71685](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/71685), it would be great if there were separate web feeds for each release.

As of 2015, the status has changed as `Confirmed → Fix Released` but the following comment in late-2017 noted that a pop-up menu allows to filter the web page by release, but not the RSS feed.

To this date, the RSS feed has yet to provide separate feeds per release.