# Is there a USN RSS feed specifically for 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, security

http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/ links to RSS (and Atom) feeds of *all* USNs (Ubuntu Security Notices). I'd love an RSS feed of *only* security updates to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Anyone know if someone has already published one? It wouldn't be hard to filter the RSS down to only the updates that are relevant to me, I'm just surprised if someone hasn't already done this.

Comment: Dup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/195513/are-there-ubuntu-security-notices-feeds-for-specific-releases